# In groupby how to refer back to the grouped columns and values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `groupedby` dataframe:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(by=['resolution','media_type', 'asset_type']).file_name.apply(list)
print (df_grouped)

# resolution  media_type  asset_type
# HD          Video       Feature       [LG_ALPHAASP_EN__L102...
#                         Promo         [Alphap_2ch.mov]
#                         Trailer       [LG_ALPHAX9_178_2...
```

How would I access all these values? For example something like:

```
for item in df_grouped:
    print (item.resolution, item.media_type, item.asset_type, item.values)
```

It seems like when I iterate over `df_grouped` I only have access to the `values` list at the end. For example:

```
for item in df_grouped:
    print(item)

# [LG_ALPHAASP_EN__L102...
# [Alphap_2ch.mov]
# [LG_ALPHAX9_178_2...
```

How would I get all?

Comment: the grouping is a dictionary, so you can use ```key:value  for key, value in group.items()```

Comment: @sammywemmy awesome, thank you! I find the Pandas documentation so hard to follow, by the way. They seem to give 100s of examples of `foo...bar` and then it's almost impossible (for me) to find something that I'm trying to accomplish, so thanks for the help!

Comment: not a problem. Cheers

Comment: @sammywemmy by the way, do you know if possible to do the following in Pandas, or not possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63408544/instantiate-a-class-in-a-groupby-apply-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpack `MultiIndex` to variables with [`Series.items`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.items.html)

```
for (resolution, media_type, asset_type), values in df_grouped.items():
    print (resolution, media_type, asset_type, values)
    
HD Video Feature [LG_ALPHAASP_EN__L102]
HD Video Promo [Alphap_2ch.mov]
HD Video Trailer [LG_ALPHAX9_178_2]
```

Another way is use indexing:

```
for index, values in df_grouped.items():
    print (index[0], index[1], index[2], values)
    
HD Video Feature [LG_ALPHAASP_EN__L102]
HD Video Promo [Alphap_2ch.mov]
HD Video Trailer [LG_ALPHAX9_178_2]
```

If convert `MultiIndex Series` to `DataFrame` with all levels to columns:

```
for item in df_grouped.reset_index(name='L').itertuples():
    print (item.resolution, item.media_type, item.asset_type, item.L)
```

Comment: thanks, you would suggest using `.items()` over the `reset_index` approach, which you had mentioned as well? Also, is `MultiIndex` the same thing as using multiple fields in a `GROUP BY` in SQL, or what exactly is a multiindex in the above context?

Comment: @David542 - Hard question, it depends what need. If need processing each row values separately first 2 ways should be better, but not possible select by variable like `resolution`, then need third.

Comment: thanks, finally, what does the `name='L'` do? I couldn't find that in the documentation on `reset_index`.

Comment: @David542 - You can find it  - [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), it create column name from values of Series, here column filled by lists

Comment: Though couldn't I just refer to the column directly? That is: `for item in df_grouped.reset_index().itertuples(): print (item.resolution, item.media_type, item.asset_type, item.file_name)` ?

Comment: @David542 - yop, if need `file_name` then no `name` parameter